Github action issue issue with `npm install`
Part of my work flow involves a step to install npm packages with the command npm install, but for some unknown reasons I am getting this error below. I am not sure what the error below is about or how to fix.


Could you share your whole workflow YAML file configuration in the question? So we can try reproducing your issue.

I guess npm not configured correctly on GitHub actions
The correct configuration should be like this:
- uses: actions/setup-node@v3
    with:
      node-version: "16"
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TESTING_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
  - run: npm config set package-lock true
  - run: echo 'package-lock=true'>> .npmrc
  - run: npm install -g npm@latest
  - run: npm i -g npm-upgrade
  - run: |
      [enter image description here][1]


The current version of setup-note is v4, so you should use actions/setup-node@v4 here and in your own workflows. (The warnings you should be seeing about node 16 being deprecated are telling you just that: bump your action versions!)

Should be quick one to do this
- name: Setup Node
  uses: actions/setup-node@v4
  with:
    node-version: 20

Below works perfectly fine on GitHub. Runner I am using is runs-on: ubuntu-latest
